# laying out button group in a ClojureScript om-bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, clojurescript, om

I'm trying to include a button group in the navbar of a ClojureScript application in which I'm using [om-bootstrap](https://github.com/racehub/om-bootstrap), but the layout isn't coming out right --- it's like the button group is interrupting the navbar's layout flow.  What I'm getting looks like this:

[image]

I'd like it to look more like this, with everything on one line:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
(fn [data owner]                                                                       
  (reify                                                                               
    om/IRender                                                                         
    (render [_]                                                                        
      (n/navbar                                                                        
       {:brand (d/a {:href "#"} "Brand")}                                              
       (n/nav                                                                          
        {:collapsible? true}                                                           
        (b/dropdown {:key 1, :title "Menu 1"}                                          
                    (b/menu-item {:key 11} "Hamburger")                                
                    (b/menu-item {:key 12} "Fries")                                    
                    )                                                                  
        (b/button-group {}                                                             
                        (b/button {} "Foo")                                            
                        (b/button {} "Bar"))                                           
        (b/dropdown {:key 2, :title "Menu 2"}                                          
                    (b/menu-item {:key 21} "Tofu")                                     
                    (b/menu-item {:key 22} "Salad")                                    
                    )                                                                  
        )))))
```

Can someone explain how to get everything on one line?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a row.
This is a sample layout from a page of mine.  I have one row, two columns.  The first column has three vertical items.  The second column contains a table.
If you set the "width" (:xs 12) and have a single column, it should take up the width of the page.  There are different settings for what I am calling width.  It decides, based on device, when things wrap.

```
        [om-bootstrap.grid :as g]

                (d/div #js {:style (utils/display (:display e-map))}
                       (p/panel {:header (str "Daily Schedule for " current-date)
                                 :bs-style "primary"
                                 :footer (utils/footer-text)}
                                (g/row {}
                                       (g/col {:class "daily-widgets"
                                               :xs 2}
                                              (om/build db/daily-buttons-widget {:display true})
                                              (om/build ds/date_scanner {:component-id :selected-daily-date :display true})
                                              (om/build summary_work/summary-work-widget {:monitor :selected-daily-date})
                                              )
                                       (g/col {:xs 10}
                                              (table {:striped? true :bordered? true :condensed? true :hover? true}
                                                     (d/thead
                                                      (d/tr
                                                       (d/th {:width "5%"} "Technician")
                                                       (d/th {:width "10%"} "Customer")
                                                       (d/th {:width "10%"} "Vehicle")
                                                       (d/th {:width "10%"} "Status")
                                                       (d/th {:width "10%"} "Checked In")
                                                       (d/th {:width "5%"} "Hours")
                                                       (d/th {:width "50%"} "Notes")
                                                       ))
                                                     (format-tbody daily-view current-date owner))
                                              )
                                       )
```

Comment: This is fine if you just want to lay stuff out in a row.  But I'm specifically interested in using the navbar component so that I can take advantage of its collapsibility (it switches to a hamburger menu when the screen is narrow enough), and this solution doesn't use a navbar.  Any idea how to make the navbar do what I want?  (I tried nesting a row/col inside a navbar, or wrapping a row/col around the navbar, but no luck.)

Comment: I think my version is too old to do all of that.  I haven't seen any options for that.  I am investigating Bootstrap outside of Om, so I may learn something new.